# generate unique mnemonic with password(only)

Tags: metamask, hd-wallets, bip39, bip32, passphrase

I am trying to create an exodus like wallet, where for the first time user just need to enter the password to register on wallet.
 
The method I thought, running PBKDF2 on the password with empty salt and using that as an entropy for entropyToMnemonic() from bip39, which I found [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/57036/generate-recover-hd-wallet-with-username-password-only).
But the problem with this method is when two users will have same password then the mnemonic will be same.
How can I get uniqueness using this method. Something like how metamask manages the wallet.

Answer (score 3):

Entropy implies randomness.

Using deterministic algorithms on a password is not entropy and **SHOULD NOT** be used!

I would recommend researching how to gather entropic data from whatever programming language you're using.

Comment: Yeah I know entropy should be completely random, but as the password will only belong to the user, I guess there shouldn't be any issue. And again with this method somehow I need some uniqueness such that two same passwords on different systems doesn't generate same entropy.

Answer (score 0):

To the entropy from the user's password, you need to add the time and date of the password creation, as well as any geolocation. In this case, the entropy will be more universal.